# date time in javascript 24 hours format

Tags: javascript, time, datetime-format

```
var date = "8-21-2012";
var time = "00:00";
var dateArr = new Array();

dateArr = date.split("-");
var timeArr = new Array();
timeArr = time.split(":");


var date1 = "8-21-2012";
var time1 = "20:00";
var dateArr1 = new Array();

dateArr1 = date1.split("-");
var timeArr1 = new Array();
timeArr1 = time1.split(":");

var birthday = new Date(parseInt(dateArr[2], 10), parseInt(dateArr[0], 10), parseInt(dateArr[1], 10), parseInt(timeArr[0], 10), parseInt(timeArr[1], 10), parseInt(00, 10));

var birthday1 = new Date(parseInt(dateArr1[2], 10), parseInt(dateArr1[0], 10), parseInt(dateArr1[1], 10), parseInt(timeArr1[0], 10), parseInt(timeArr1[1], 10), parseInt(00, 10));
```

Now in first time it's 00 means 24 hours
Birthday object should be greater logically but it's showing birthday1 in greater. It's unable to compare this 00 time. Other than that everything is fine.
Please help.

Comment: on the same date, 0000 is less than 2000.  Unless I misunderstand the question.

Comment: 00 means 24 hours mid night and little back from new date.

Comment: Seems to me when you are assigning the time 00:00 it is refering 12 am, means start of the date

Comment: It's showing 00:00:00 time with date.

Comment: yes.  that is the start of the day.  if you want the start of the next day, the date would need to change.

Comment: Hi NappingRabbit Thanks a lot, My issue is solved now.

Answer (score 0):

> on the same date, 0000 is less than 2000. 
>   if you want the start of the next day, the date would need to change.